Adding Constraints to view, whose topAnchor's is bottomAnchor of UIView with dynamic height
I've created a UIView, which has buttons in it. I set the constraints like this :
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    sampleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
    sampleView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
    sampleView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
])

Not added any height or bottom anchor as I want it to be dynamic in height.
Initially sampleView has no buttons, so it doesn't appear in UI. I then add buttons in it vertical to each other and it works fine.
The problem I'm facing right now is, there is another view(tempView) just below this sampleView. And initially I set tempView's topAnchor to sampleView's bottomAnchor.
So it is placed properly on screen initially.
When I add  buttons in sampleView, it expands, but tempView don't. I tried with view.layoutIfNeeded() and setting the topAnchor with new height of sampleView but nothing works out for me.

could you add a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve? did you set your translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false?

What is sampleView? Is it addedSkillsView??? Most likely, when you "add buttons to sampleView" you are not setting up the bottom constraint, so it has no height. Set sampleView.clipsToBounds = true ... if you don't see any of the buttons you are adding, it will be clear that you're not supplying any constraints to give it a height.

@AlejandroL.Rocha, yes I set that to add constraints. Dont have screenshot, but I can try to explain. I have created a sampleView with dynamic height and it will have multiple buttons in vertical order. There is one more view(tempView) on screen just below this sampleView. As my sampleView dont have fix height, I'm unable to put new tempView below sampleView dynamically.  If I add more content in sampleView, sampleView is overlapping tempView

Can you share the diagram of your UI i.e how you want your views to be placed? You can use https://app.diagrams.net/ to make the blueprint of your views and share it here, that way it would be easier to look into your problem.

Can you please share the button and tempview constraint?

@Pratik https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mPORaumyYe9zTylE5v6IG7cbLWKw_XAh/view?usp=sharing

@Berlin
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
tempView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:sampleView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20),
tempView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
])

@Berlin
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
optionButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sampleView.topAnchor, constant: CGFloat(currentLine) * (buttonHeight + buttonSpacing)),
optionButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sampleView.leadingAnchor, constant: currentXPosition),
optionButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: buttonHeight)
])

@ajay_sarkate is there any subview inside tempview?

If I understand this correctly, You want to make sure that your temp view should always be at the bottom of your sample view even if you add n numbers of buttons to your sample view?

@ajay_sarkate I understand your question. This issue occur due to missing bottom constraint or your Button which is added in SampleView.  please add bottom constraint of your last button to sampleview bottom constraint. and  it will start working as aspected.
also I put my code as answer kindly check it.

Use a UIStackView, it will grow dinamically depending on the amount of buttons that you have

You must do something to give sampleView a Height.
One easy way is to add a vertical UIStackView as a subview of sampleView, constrain all 4 sides to sampleView, and then add buttons as arranged subviews of the stack view.
Quick example:
class ExampleVC: UIViewController {
    
    let topView = UIView()
    let sampleView = UIView()
    let tempView = UIView()
    
    // let's use a vertical stack view to hold the buttons inside sampleView
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        [topView, sampleView, tempView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        topView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        sampleView.backgroundColor = .green
        tempView.backgroundColor = .cyan
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            topView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            topView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            topView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0),
            
            sampleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            sampleView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            sampleView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            // sampleView has no Height constraint ...
            //  we're adding a stack view to it, and as we add buttons to the stack view
            //  it will control the Height
            
            tempView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sampleView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            tempView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            tempView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            tempView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0),
            
        ])
        
        // stackView to hold the buttons
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 8
        
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sampleView.addSubview(stackView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain all 4 sides of the stack view to sampleView
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sampleView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sampleView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sampleView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sampleView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
        ])
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let btnNumber = stackView.arrangedSubviews.count + 1
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.backgroundColor = .red
        btn.setTitle("Button \(btnNumber)", for: [])
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(btn)
    }
    
}

At start, because we haven't added any buttons to the stack view, it will look like this:

Tap anywhere to add buttons -- here is what we get after the first tap:

and after a couple more taps:


Edit - quick example #2...
You didn't include any information about how you are arranging the buttons horizontal to each other if fitted in one line else new button will down to previous -- but here is one approach.
Add a variable Height constraint as a property to your controller class:
// this will be updated when we add buttons
var sampleViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

We will initialize sampleViewHeightConstraint as the .heightAnchor of sampleView, with a constant of Zero.
When we add button(s) to sampleView, we will calculate where the new button should be placed (i.e. "wrapping to the next row" if we've reached the edge of the view).
We will then update sampleViewHeightConstraint.constant based on the bottom of the last button added:
class Example2VC: UIViewController {
    
    let topView = UIView()
    let sampleView = UIView()
    let tempView = UIView()

    // this will be updated when we add buttons
    var sampleViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    let btnTitles: [String] = [
        "here", "are some", "sample", "button", "titles",
        "so we have", "varying width", "buttons",
        "that will be arranged", "on rows fitting",
        "inside", "this view",
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        [topView, sampleView, tempView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        topView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        sampleView.backgroundColor = .green
        tempView.backgroundColor = .cyan
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        // initialize the sampleViewHeightConstraint
        sampleViewHeightConstraint = sampleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.0)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            topView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            topView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            topView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0),
            
            sampleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            sampleView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            sampleView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            // sampleViewHeightConstraint will be updated when we add buttons
            sampleViewHeightConstraint,
            
            tempView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sampleView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            tempView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            tempView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            tempView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0),
            
        ])
        
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        
        let thisTitle: String = btnTitles[sampleView.subviews.count % btnTitles.count]

        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.backgroundColor = .red
        btn.setTitle(thisTitle, for: [])
        
        let sz: CGSize = btn.intrinsicContentSize
        // let's make the button frame a little wider than the title
        btn.frame = .init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: sz.width + 16.0, height: sz.height)

        if sampleView.subviews.count == 0 {
            // this is the first button we're adding,
            //  so put it at 8,8
            btn.frame.origin = .init(x: 8.0, y: 8.0)
        } else {
            if let lastBtn = sampleView.subviews.last {
                btn.frame.origin = .init(x: lastBtn.frame.maxX + 8.0, y: lastBtn.frame.minY)
                if btn.frame.maxX > sampleView.frame.width - 8.0 {
                    // extends past the right edge, so "move it down a row"
                    btn.frame.origin = .init(x: 8.0, y: lastBtn.frame.maxY + 8.0)
                }
            }
        }

        // add the new button
        sampleView.addSubview(btn)
        
        // update the sampleViewHeightConstraint
        if let lastBtn = sampleView.subviews.last {
            sampleViewHeightConstraint.constant = lastBtn.frame.maxY + 8.0
        }
        
    }
    
}

as with the first example, it starts out like this:

we tap anywhere to add a button:

tap a few times to add more buttons:

the next button will exceed the view width, so we "wrap" it:

another tap:

and after a bunch of taps:

However you are adding the buttons and arranging them, the key point is that you must do something to give sampleView a height... updating the .constant value of a constraint as shown in this example is one way to do so.

Thanks, this helped to understand this concept. I more thing, is there any way instead of vertical stack view? I want to add buttons dynamically, they will be horizontal to each other if fitted in one line else new button will down to previous.

@ajay_sarkate check my answer I manage without stackview.

@ajay_sarkate - of course you don't need to use a stack view. You didn't show us any code related to "arranging the buttons", so I added an Edit to my answer to show you one approach.
